# Spring boot: Access only associated column value in JPA without fetching the complete associated entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities. one entity is associated to other.

```
@Entity
Class Author{
@Id
Long id;

@Column(name = "author_id")
private Ling authorId;
}


@Entity
class Book{
@Id
Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@column(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "author_id")
Author author;
}
```

Here ,assume all getters and setters set. author_id of Author is being saved in my Book entity table.

```
Book book = Book.findById(1);
book.getAuthor().getAuthorId();
```

When I do this, even when author_id is stored in my book table, I am not able to directly access it. Here it fires another sql query to fetch the author entity and then return the author_id. Is there a way to directly access author_id.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `Author` is a **LAZY** association in `Book` entity. 
This means that it wont be part of the original query fetching the book:

```
Book book = Book.findById(1);
```

That would be triggered by accessing any property of that lazy association:

```
book.getAuthor().getAuthorId();
```

What you are looking for, it seems, is a projection which is JPQL would be:

```
select a.id
from Book b
  inner join b.author a
where b.id = :id
```

Comment: Here, I need complete book entity too. My doubt is that, when I fetch book entity, it fetches complete row which also includes author_id. So, I want to access this author_id without any extra query on DB.

Comment: Thats not how orm in JPA works. You either get complete entities or you project everything in the query.